# Continuous integration and deployment with jBPM

Tags: continuous-integration, jbpm

We are using jBPM EAP 6.4 version. We are developing the JBPM workflows and rules using business central console tool.

We want to implement Continuous integration in our project. How can we implement the CI if we use Business central console for our changes ? Normally Jenkins (other build server) listens repository server for changes, as soon as developer pushes the changes to repository, immediately it will trigger the build and deploy.

But in our case we are developing everything using the console.How to achieve CI in this special case or any recommended approach to implement CI in jBPM ?

Can you please suggest..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a pointer,

The work bench (business central control) is pointing to a git repository (by default), so essentially,  when you are interacting to the work bench, you are doing actions very similar to a normal scenario, that is, where a developer commits to a git repository.

[User documentation jBPM - VFS repository](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch09.html#wb.VFSRepository)

Hope this gives a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories in Business Central use virtual file system based on Git and each time you save something in one of the editors a commit is made. You can create a [Git hook](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/chap_repository_hooks.html) on your repository which will trigger some action after each commit.